# Как выполнить поиск по модели Django

Tags: python, html, django, views

Дано: id контракта (например 32812) получить из обьектов модели кредитной заявки (!!!) уникальные id производителей всех товаров, которые связаны с этим контрактом при выполнении постараться минимизировать обращение к базе данных

```
class Credit(models.Model):
    """
    Кредитная заявка. Только один контракт но несколько товаров

    """
    name_credit = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name='name_credit',null=True)
    contract = models.ForeignKey('Contract',
                                 verbose_name='contract', related_name='contract', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # product = models.ForeignKey('Product',
    #                             verbose_name='product',
    #                             related_name='product',
    #                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name='date', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name_credit

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Кредитная заявка '
        verbose_name_plural = 'Кредитные заявки'


class Contract(models.Model):
    """
    Контракт связан с кредитной заявкой

    """
    #product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product', null=True)
    contracts = models.TextField(max_length=200,
                                verbose_name='contracts')

    date = models.DateField(verbose_name='date', blank=True, null=True)
    credit = models.ForeignKey(Credit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,related_name='credit')
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer',
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.contracts

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Контракт '
        verbose_name_plural = 'Контракты'


class Product(models.Model):
    """
    Товар имеет только одного производителя

    """
    credit = models.ForeignKey(Credit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    products = models.TextField(max_length=100, verbose_name='products')
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer',
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='manufacturer', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.products

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Товар'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товары'


class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    """
    Производитель производит только один продукт

    """
    name = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name='name')
    #product = models.ManyToManyField('Product', related_name='product')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Производитель'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Производители'
```

что написать во вьюхе  что бы найти id товара находящегося в контракте?
Как я думаю. У меня есть id контракта наверное через форму как то сделать. что бы потом Id перехватить и вставить во вьюху. после чего ищем в кредитной заявке Id завода.. PLZ help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я многое переделал. Именно в моделях.

```
from django.db import models


class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Производитель"
        verbose_name_plural = "Производители"


class CreditBit(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    contract = models.OneToOneField('Contract', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="creditbits")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Кредитная заявка"
        verbose_name_plural = "Кредитные заявки"


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products", null=True)
    creditbit = models.ForeignKey('CreditBit', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Продукт"
        verbose_name_plural = "Продукты"


class Contract(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Контракт"
        verbose_name_plural = "Контракты"
```

И после написал нужный запрос
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .models import Contract, CreditBit
from .forms import IdForm


class MyView(View):

form = IdForm

def post(self, request):
    form = IdForm(request.POST)
    context_dict = {'form': self.form}

    if form.is_valid():
        contract_id = form.cleaned_data.get("contract_id")
        creditbit = CreditBit.objects.filter(contract_id=contract_id).first()

        if not creditbit:
            return render(request, template_name="contract.html", context={'form': self.form})

        list_ids = list(creditbit.products.all().distinct()
                        .values_list("manufacturer__pk", flat=True))

        # Просто для души
        list_names = list(creditbit.products.all().distinct()
                          .values_list("manufacturer__name", flat=True))

        context_dict.update({'list_ids': list_ids, 'list_names': list_names})

    return render(request, template_name="contract.html", context=context_dict)

def get(self, request):
    return render(request, template_name="contract.html", context={'form': self.form})
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант простого поиска, попробуй

```
from django.db.models import Q

def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    contracts = Contract.objects.filter(Q(credit.id__icontains=query) )

    context = {
        'query': query,
        'contracts': contracts
    }
return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```